# Stripe payment links

Tags: email, stripe-payments, payment

I'm trying to take payments on stripe. I have there email address's. However they all owe different amounts, varying from £0.99 to £599.99. I want to send each one a payment link with the correct amount.

I have tried making a payment link however this would mean i would need to make a payment link and product for each payer. This is less than ideal.

Ideally there i would be able to feed stripe a spreadsheet and have it send out payment links for each customer.

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such feature to bulk create / send payment links at the moment.

Comment: Do you know of any other provider that would offer such a service, i have been looking at Zoho checkout

Comment: sorry, i'm not aware of any

Answer (score 0):

Check this; https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links/api
You can create a payment link for every individual user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://zerotasker.com/stripeexcel.html which lets you create bulk Payment link from an excel sheet. Hopefully this fits your requirement.

Disclaimer : I created this product.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).